# CSS - calling an id within a class in an UL to show a div on hover

Tags: html, css, class, hover

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="wordsmith">
    <p>WORDSMITH: dummy text here.</p>
</div>

<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="wordsmith">The Wordsmith</a></li>
        <li><a id="tracksmith">The Tracksmith</a></li>
        <li><a id="nerdsmith">The Nerdsmith</a></li>
        <li><a id="family">The Family Man</li>          
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
        text-align: center;
    }

.wordsmith {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        max-width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 15px;
        display: none;
    }

.menu #wordsmith:hover ~ .wordsmith {
        display: block;
    }
```

I have a menu centered in the middle of the page with text links in an UL. What I'm trying to achieve is on hovering over one of the menu items, a div with information will appear up top. The original solution to this I found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/n5fzB/2/) (JS Fiddle). If I try to achieve this outside of a div and UL, everything works. As soon as I put the menu items in a div OR an UL, the CSS breaks. Am I calling the CSS selector correctly with the ".menu #wordsmith" part? Any help is appreciated! Keep in mind, I'm trying to do this strictly with CSS and html, not JS. Thanks.

Comment: because it is not the sibling of `a` you will need to use jQuery or javascript

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the are no predecessor or ancestor combinators/selectors so this is not possible in CSS. [`~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) is the general sibling combinator and `#wordsmith` and `.wordsmith` are not siblings, `.wordsmith` is a predecessor of an ancestor of `#wordsmith`.
If you really need to do this you'll have to use JavaScript or re-factor your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/n5fzB/229/

with jQuery you can do this

```js
$("#f").hover(
  function() {
    $('.ab').css('display', 'block');
    $('.a').css('display', 'none');
  },
  function() {
    $('.ab').css('display', 'none');
    $('.a').css('display', 'block');
  }
);
$("#s").hover(
  function() {
    $('.abc').css('display', 'block');
    $('.a').css('display', 'none');
  },
  function() {
    $('.abc').css('display', 'none');
    $('.a').css('display', 'block');
  }
);
```

```css
.abc,.ab {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a id="f">Show First content!</a></li>
  <li><a id="s">Show Second content!!</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="a">Default Content</div>
<div class="ab">First content</div>
<div class="abc">Second content</div>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. I realize now that what I was trying to do had to be a parent / child relationship. The div's I have on this page are not. Maybe I can create a main "container" div this way everything is technically in the same hierarchy and go from there.

Comment: Nope. A container div doesn't do anything to solve the problem. I see that the issue is the relationship with #wordsmith and .wordsmith. Those are not parent / child related.

Answer (score 0):

Musa is right, you can't target `#wordsmith` and do something with another element that isn't a sibling or child. But you can do something else. (disclaimer: I don't love using `absolute`  positioning and I treat it as a last result) But if this *has* to be done with CSS only...you could put the text inside the `li` and use `position:absolute` to display it above like you wanted. Check out the fiddle below to see what I mean:

HTML

```
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
        <a id="wordsmith">The Wordsmith</a>
        <p>WORDSMITH: dummy text here.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="tracksmith">The Tracksmith</a>
        <p>TRACKSMITH: dummy text here.</p>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="nerdsmith">The Nerdsmith</a>
        <p>NERDSMITH: dummy text here.</p>        
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="family">The Family Man</a>
        <p>FAMILY: dummy text here.</p>        
    </li>          
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 0 0;
}

.wordsmith {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
}

.menu ul{
    position: relative;
}

.menu li p{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;  
}

.menu li a:hover + p{
    display: block;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/b54osvqq/1/)